# How to pass array form one view to another view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to i phone programming.I have store some data in array that i want to pass that array data form one view to another view.What i am tried but its not working.Can any body tell me what is mistake in that.

#import"firstviewcontroller.h"

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tapCollection;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *imageCollection;
```

#import"firstviewcontroller.m"

```
   @synthesize imageCollection,tapCollection;
    -(void)viewdidload
    {
    self.tapCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.imageCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    - (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
    {

        secondviewcontroller*r= [[secondviewcontrolleralloc] initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
         r.imageCollection1 =imageCollection;
             r.tapCollection1 =tapCollection;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:r animated:YES];

    }
```

Acctually what data i store in array is images and button tag values.Here in console its displaying  Images and button tag value i have store in array

```
2013-03-19 21:54:03.374 Taukyy[290:1c103] (
    0,
    "<UIImage: 0x9cd59e0>",
    1,
    "<UIImage: 0x9cd6220>",
    2,
    "<UIImage: 0x9cd6b70>"
)
```

## import"secondviewcontroller.h"

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tapCollection1;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *imageCollection1;
```

## import"secondviewcontroller.m"

```
@synthesize tapCollection1,imageCollection1;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    imageCollection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   tapCollection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSLog(@"%@",tapCollection1);
   NSLog(@"%@",imageCollection1);
}
```

But here values are not displaying.Its showing as below

```
2013-03-19 21:29:16.379 Taukyy[594:1c103] (
)
2013-03-19 21:29:16.380 Taukyy[594:1c103] (
)
2013-03-19 21:29:16.381 Taukyy[594:1c103] (
)
```

Please can any body tell me what is mistake in this code
Thanks
Aslam

Comment: It's data.  You reach it using an address, not a name.  Having the same-named object with a different address does you no good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `viewDidLoad's` array allocations from `secondviewcontroller.m`

You `tapCollection1` & `imageCollection1` are `retain` properties.So It should `retain` the assigned objects.

Your **secondviewcontroller.h** should look like,

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tapCollection1;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *imageCollection1;
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  //remove the allocation codes
}
```

You can log it in **firstviewcontroller.m**  like,

```
 - (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
    {

         secondviewcontroller*r= [[secondviewcontrolleralloc] initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
         self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
         r.imageCollection1 =imageCollection;
         r.tapCollection1 =tapCollection;
         NSLog(@"%@",r.imageCollection1);
         NSLog(@"%@",r.tapCollection1);
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:r animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: +1 nice explanation...but you have to format it so other one can easily understand

Answer (score 3):

Don't allocate/initialize your arrays again. You set them when you're preparing your segue.

```
@synthesize tapCollection1,imageCollection1;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   //imageCollection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   //tapCollection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSLog(@"%@",tapCollection1);
   NSLog(@"%@",imageCollection1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not `init` the `mutableArrays` in `viewDidLoad` of `SecondViewController` ,
instead do it in the `init` method of `SecondViewController`

```
 -(id)initWithNibName //this method
  {
     //create object

      self.imageCollection1 = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      self.tapCollection1 = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   }
```

You will get the right values now..

Answer (score 0):

Why are you allocating previously allocated array.

just remove

```
imageCollection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tapCollection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```